# Pattern matching much faster than just checking flag in object!!? Why?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I thought pattern matching would be MUCH, MUCH slower than just having a `isFooObject` flag in your object that indicates that the object is an instance of class `Foo`. I was so wrong!

Here is the runnable code for my experiment https://dotnetfiddle.net/E6LYjw and below is my code:

```
        var obj1 = new Foo { Id = 123, Name = "12341", isFooObj = true };
        var watch1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for(int i=0; i<100 000 000; i++) {
                if (obj1.isFooObj) { // Do something }
            }
        watch1.Stop();
        
        var watch2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for(int i=0; i<100 000 000; i++) {
                if(obj1 is Foo) { //Do something }
            }
        watch2.Stop();
```

Turns out, the pattern matching method is about twice as fast as checking the flag!
Is this true or is my testing methodology wrong? If it is true, why? I thought pattern matching would be much slower because the whole object needs to be checked to see if it matches `Foo`.

Comment: _"the whole object "_ - the type metadata is readily accessible to the runtime and highly optimized. There's also probably some compiler magic involved here, as it can determine at compile time that `obj1` is, in fact, a `Foo` all 100 million times you check it.

Comment: Indeed - and given that the type of `obj1` is `Foo`, you're *really* just saying "Is the value non-null?"

Answer (score 0):

isFooObj incurrs a null check for a reference type.